# Visual impairment support on Android?

Tags: accessibility

Perhaps this is somewhat of a software recommendation but I hope people will realize it is a  very important and relevant one (plus, one shouldn't need to download an app, it should be part of the OS). On PCs there is something called SuperNova software which will allow you to view larger text on PCs. On Android it is possible to pich and spread the fingers apart to view larger web pages (and this works on most pages), but what I need is I need to be able to do the same on things like settings pages and contact lists. I wonder whether there is some way to support this functionality on Android devices (Android comes with good support for people with restricted motion of the limbs, and I was wondering why support for visual impairment that allows to zoom by reverse-pinching is not included).

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: [How to help Android users with reduced ability to see](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3798/981), [Is there a user accessible font size preference?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2202/981), [Is there a larger interface for older owners?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/68315/981)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings --> Display --> Font size will adjust the font from "tiny" right through "huge" on the system pages (like Settings) on the two Samsung devices I have.  Tinkering with brightness and mode can also help boost contrast.  If you head over to Settings -- > Accessibility --> Vision, there are additional/duplicate adjustments for magnification gestures, color adjustment, and negative colors.